# How do you get Material-UI Drawer to highlight the page it is currently at?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, material-design, react-router-v4

I'm currently trying to implement a website using [Material-UI's drawer component](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#drawer). It works, when I click on the Drawer Items, it routes me to the correct pages.
But how do I get the individual Drawer Items to highlight the current page it is on.

For instance, if I am on /dashboard page, and if the Drawer Item for Dashboard page should be highlighted (different color and styles) to indicate that I am currently on that page dynamically.

Haven't manage to find any good solutions online and the Material-UI docs doesn't have a demo of how this is possible, great to hear how you all do it.

Answer (score 7):

You can highlight the current `ListItem` in the `Drawer` by setting `selected` props to `true` and use the `pathname` information to determine if the item matches the current route:

```js
const routes = {
  Home: "/",
  About: "/about",
  Users: "/users"
};
```

```js
const { pathname } = useLocation();
```

```js
<List>
  {Object.keys(routes).map((routeName, index) => {
    const route = routes[routeName];

    return (
      <ListItem selected={route === pathname} button key={route}>
        <ListItemText primary={routeName} />
      </ListItem>
    );
  })}
</List>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67026979/how-do-you-get-material-ui-drawer-to-highlight-the-page-it-is-currently-at]